# How to get payout data in Stripe Connect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, payout

I'm adding Stripe Connect to my app to send payments to the users,I need to create a payment dashboard where each user can see all the payments that were sent to them( like payment history). I've read here https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts/create that I can retrieve list of all payouts or individual payout(by submitting payout id), but I can't find information on how to get payout data per user. For example, if I have user John Doe, I want to get all the payout information for John only with 1 API call, is it possible in Stripe Connect?

Comment: how are you sending payments to the users - are you using direct charges, separate charges and transfers, or destination charges? See https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges

Comment: did you figure this out? we have the same problem in that this api takes in a destination as a bank account not the connected account...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the list of payments on the connected account, you should [retrieve the list of Charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list) using the [stripeAccount header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication).

You can also make use of the [auto-pagination built into Stripe SDKs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/auto) to loop through the list.

Example

```
for await (const charge of stripe.charges.list({stripeAccount: 'connected_account_id'})) {
    // Do something with charge
    console.log(charge);
  }
```

You may want to reach out to Stripe to check if you're eligible to use this beta where you can embed a payments dashboard component into your site : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/get-started-connect-embedded-uis

Answer (score 0):

You can get payout data for a stripe connect account using:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('API_KEY');

const payouts = await stripe.payouts.list({
  limit: 10,
}, { stripeAccount: 'Connect Account Id' });
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand goodly your question, you want to retrieve connected accounts' payouts.

You have to know that *payout* api using is when you move money on your account. In the other hand, if you want to move money to any connected account you need to use *transfert* api.

**Code**

*You need to know user connect account*

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('API_KEY');

const transfers = await stripe.transfers.list({
  destination: 'acct_id.....',
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but I need to retreive payout information for 1 connected account only, not all the connected accounts.

Comment: @alia With this code, by putting the connected account id as destination parameter, you'll be able to retrieve all payout information of this connected account.